# BeautifulSoup unable to find Image Src attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, error-handling

Hi so I have been web scraping the [Asos fashion website](https://www.asos.com/men/shoes-boots-trainers/boots/cat/?cid=5774&currentpricerange=15-400&nlid=mw%7Cshoes%7Cshop%20by%20product%7Cboots&refine=attribute_1046:8222,8629,10808&sort=priceasc) and I get all the elements but unable to get `img` source attribute after the 8th `img`.

The `img` class consists of three names or the name could belong? which is a bit fishy.

When I try to find all `img` tags I get a very different name with no source attribute for the 9th `img`

**My Code:**

```
from helium import*
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = start_firefox(f"https://www.asos.com/men/shoes-boots-trainers/boots/cat/?cid=5774&currentpricerange=15-400&nlid=mw|shoes|shop%20by%20product|boots&refine=attribute_1046:8222,8629,10808&sort=priceasc",headless =True)

time.sleep(5)

for x in range(1,2):
    scroll_down(num_pixels=10000)
    for x in range(1,3):
        click("LOAD MORE")
        time.sleep(5)
        scroll_down(num_pixels=10000)


soup = BeautifulSoup(s.page_source,"lxml")

All = soup.find_all("article",class_="_2qG85dG")

kill_browser()

   
def img(s):
    try:
        return s.find("img",class_= "_2r9Zh0W")["src"]
    except:
        return s.find("img",class_="_2FC97Nq _2q4fCfJ _2r9Zh0W")['src']

for a in All:
    print(img(a))
    print()
```

**Output:**

```
//images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-chelsea-boots-in-tan-faux-suede/12550524-1-tan?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

//images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-chelsea-boots-in-black-faux-suede/12550506-1-black?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

//images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-chelsea-boots-in-brown-suede-with-black-sole/14849004-1-brown?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

//images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-vegan-lace-up-boots-in-brown-faux-leather/12510724-1-brown?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

//images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-chelsea-boots-in-brown-leather-with-brown-sole/10278706-1-brown?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

//images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-cuban-heel-western-chelsea-boot-in-grey-faux-suede-with-square-toe-with-metal-cap/21031115-1-grey?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

//images.asos-media.com/products/new-look-chelsea-boot-in-black-suede/21198040-1-black?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

//images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-wide-fit-chelsea-boots-in-black-faux-suede/12550515-1-black?$n_480w$&wid=476&fit=constrain

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-d9272492986c> in img(s)
      9     try:
---> 10         return s.find("img",class_= "_2r9Zh0W")["src"]
     11     except:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-51d9d651c40b> in <module>
      3     #print(a.find("div",class_= "_3J74XsK").text.strip())
      4     #print(price(a))
----> 5     print(img(a))
      6     print()

<ipython-input-78-d9272492986c> in img(s)
     10         return s.find("img",class_= "_2r9Zh0W")["src"]
     11     except:
---> 12         return s.find("img",class_="_2FC97Nq _2q4fCfJ _2r9Zh0W")["src"]
     13 
     14 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Are you sure of the structure of the page? I.e. compared to "normal" rendering, would it be possible that some kind of lazy loading could defeat your code?

Comment: Well actully wen u change the fucntion in the except block to None.   We will get images till 8th then 9th to some number it shows none. And then again it returns the images links again and then None again.                                 can you please give the code a try :)

Comment: Did you try just to find html elements in your articles, that provide a `src` attribute? I think that can be done with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

Images are loading in lazy mode, that means if they come into view. That is why you only get the `src` of the first 8th.

For image not loaded yet you will get the following information:

```
<img alt="" class="_1Jj-2sd" data-auto-id="productTileEmptyImage"/>
```

### How to fix?

Do not scroll the whole way in one step, make smaller steps and wait for the images to load:

```
for x in range(1,6):
    scroll_down(num_pixels=1800)
    time.sleep(3)
```

I also think it would be better / more clearly to select the images by it´s data attribute instead of its´s class/classes:

```
    if a.find('img', {'data-auto-id':'productTileImage'}):
        print(a.find('img', {'data-auto-id':'productTileImage'})['src'])
    else:
        print(a.img)
```

**Example**

```
from helium import*
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = start_firefox(f"https://www.asos.com/men/shoes-boots-trainers/boots/cat/?cid=5774&currentpricerange=15-400&nlid=mw|shoes|shop%20by%20product|boots&refine=attribute_1046:8222,8629,10808&sort=priceasc",headless =False)

time.sleep(2)
for t in range(1,4):
    time.sleep(2)
    for x in range(1,6):
        scroll_down(num_pixels=2000)
        time.sleep(3)
    try:
        click(Link('Load more'))
    except:
        continue

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.page_source,'lxml')


for a in soup.find_all("article",{'data-auto-id':'productTile'}):
    if a.find('img', {'data-auto-id':'productTileImage'}):
        print(a.find('img', {'data-auto-id':'productTileImage'})['src'])
    else:
        print(a.img)
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply.. but there is also a click button of LOAD MORE. So first it shows 72 items and when I click it shows the other 72 and so on.                                               Wait.. let me load all the items and then try to scroll up again.

Comment: Of course you have to click the button to load more articles, take a look in the example I updated it so that it continues its job.

Comment: Thank u so much.. it has worked u r awesome. Had to delay the time a little bit :)